# XAMPP: Error Apache shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have trouble when connecting the Apache server with XAMPP, it gives me the error status below

> ```
> Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly
> This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
> improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
> Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
> the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
> ```

**Here is the error logs given below**

```
[Tue Apr 20 12:18:09.595619 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 15252:tid 512] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Apr 20 12:18:09.651263 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 15252:tid 512] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Apr 20 12:18:10.196918 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15252:tid 512] AH00455: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1j PHP/8.0.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 20 12:18:10.196918 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15252:tid 512] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Feb 17 2021 13:11:14
[Tue Apr 20 12:18:10.196918 2021] [core:notice] [pid 15252:tid 512] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\\system and apps\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/System and Apps/XAMPP/apache'
[Tue Apr 20 12:18:10.199767 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15252:tid 512] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6092
[Tue Apr 20 12:18:10.531312 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 6092:tid 564] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Apr 20 12:18:10.586416 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 6092:tid 564] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Apr 20 12:18:10.605417 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6092:tid 564] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

So, what I need to do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using a Windows device, you can follow these four steps to update your default port settings in XAMPP.

**I hope [this](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/xampp-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly/#:%7E:text=The%20XAMPP%20error%20%E2%80%9CApache%20shutdown%20unexpectedly%E2%80%9D%20is%20commonly%20caused%20by,using%20the%20default%20Apache%20port.&text=You%20can%20do%20this%20by%20editing%20the%20httpd.,file%20(for%20Windows%20users).) will Help YOU**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it's best to include the most important bits in the question itself. Links can be broken in the future, in which case this answer will no longer be useful.